# How can I tell if an identifier is invalid in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection

I supposed I would find this in either scala-reflect or scala-compiler, but I have not been able to find a documented API for this. Is there a way to do this at runtime?

e.g. `def isValidIdentifer(s:String)`

(I am not interested in the actual list of reserved keywords, which I can write myself reading the manual)

## Edit:

Based on @sschaef's answer, additional spec : it should handle any kind of input and return true if `s` is a single valid identifier

I tried expanding this answer :

```
import scala.tools.reflect.{ToolBox, ToolBoxError}

lazy val tb = scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()

def isIdentifier(ident: String): Boolean = {
  if (ident.startsWith(" ") || ident.endsWith(" ")) {
    return false
  }
  try {
    val tree = tb.parse(s"val $ident:Int = 0")
    if (tree.toString().length != ident.length + 13) {
      return false
    }
    tree.children match {
      case c0 :: c1 :: Nil if
      c0.children.isEmpty && c0.productArity == 1 && c0.productElement(0).toString == "Int"
        && c1.children.isEmpty && c1.productArity == 1 && c1.productElement(0).toString == "Constant(0)" => true
      case _ => false
    }

  } catch {
    case _: ToolBoxError => false
  }
}
```

This succeeds for the following vicious cases: `b:Int`, `b = 0; c`, `b/*comment*/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the compiler I found this:

```
    case 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' |
         'F' | 'G' | 'H' | 'I' | 'J' |
         'K' | 'L' | 'M' | 'N' | 'O' |
         'P' | 'Q' | 'R' | 'S' | 'T' |
         'U' | 'V' | 'W' | 'X' | 'Y' |
         'Z' | '$' | '_' |
         'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' |
         'f' | 'g' | 'h' | 'i' | 'j' |
         'k' | 'l' | 'm' | 'n' | 'o' |
         'p' | 'q' | 'r' | 's' | 't' |
         'u' | 'v' | 'w' | 'x' | 'y' | // scala-mode: need to understand multi-line case patterns
         'z' =>
      putChar(ch)
      nextChar()
      getIdentRest()
```

This is part of the [scanner](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/b4ff1e934f36af6792b29b3d850cee836aa7b050/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/Scanners.scala#L409-423). Furthermore take a look to the [section](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/b4ff1e934f36af6792b29b3d850cee836aa7b050/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/Scanners.scala#L605-680) that parses the identifier rest. It doesn't look like you can easily copy or use the code.

I suggest using the toolbox:

```
scala> import scala.tools.reflect.{ToolBox, ToolBoxError}
import scala.tools.reflect.{ToolBox, ToolBoxError}

scala> val tb = scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror(
    getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
tb: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@6c865bc6

scala> def isIdentifier(ident: String) =
    try { tb.parse(s"val ($ident) = 0"); true }
    catch { case _: ToolBoxError => false }
isIdentifier: (ident: String)Boolean

scala> isIdentifier("hello")
res0: Boolean = true

scala> isIdentifier("hello_-")
res1: Boolean = true

scala> isIdentifier("hello-")
res2: Boolean = false

scala> isIdentifier("`hello-`")
res3: Boolean = true
```

Comment: This solution does not handle whitespace correctly. `isIdentifier("x = 0; val b")`

Comment: @mauhiz I surrounded the inserted code with parentheses, hopefully that is enough safefy. The use case of evaluating this function with the input of an text field from a website was not a requirement mentioned in the question... ;)

Comment: Right, I was not really clear about it. Still  `isIdentifier("x) = 0; val (b")` ;) The try-to-parse solution will be weak to injections as long as we blindly allow the input to contain whitespaces.